# Get back the funds I send to avax smart contract that I made

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, avax

can somebody help me with this contract I made?

I put in 15.99 avax to this smart contract I made for the 1st time in my life. It was with this code that I didn't made:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUWoSZ5waoMshsVQqKCRTqJtrHqccvGTt2CUnQS2YsTNA

It came from this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKVulD3UbGQ&ab_channel=CodeWithJoe

I really would like to get my 15.99 avax back, but I don't know how to make that deposit from the contract I made to my wallet.

Is there somebody who would like to help me with this (I hope not mistake) ?

Peace,

Koen

Comment: It is a scam contract. You should never deploy a contract you fail to understand.